# How can growl be used with syslog?

Tags: growl

I have a shell script that logs messages to syslog using the 'logger' command. In my syslog.conf, I filter those messages to a specific log file. This is a portable solution that works across all unices. On OS X, I would also like to have these messages sent to growl. I have tried both of the following with no success:

```
*.*        |exec /usr/local/bin/growlnotify
*.*        @127.0.0.1:23052
```

Answer (score 2):

According to `man syslog.conf`, Mac OS X's `syslog.conf` can handle messages only by writing to a file, sending to a remote host's syslog, and send them to users' consoles.

---

Your best option is probably to send to a file, and write a daemon or a periodically running script that consumes this file and calls `growlnotify` with what it reads from the file, something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line
do
    /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Your App" -m "$line"
done < /path/to/file
echo -n > /path/to/file
```

Either keep this running all the time by wrapping in a loop, or start it every few seconds using a `launchd` job and the `StartInterval` directive. `man launchd` and `man launchd.plist` can help you here.